# Haskell curl missing content on status 401

Tags: haskell, libcurl, http-status-code-401

I have some problems with the `curl` haskell library in the latest version 1.3.7.

Some example in Haskell:

```
module CurlTest where

import Network.Curl

url = "http://www.example.com/private/"
opts = [CurlFollowLocation True]

main = withCurlDo $ do
    curlGet url opts
    return ()
```

I run this snippet with ghci and I didn't get any output. On public sites with status-code 200 I get the page-content. With pure `curl` from the command-line I get the page-content even on 401 sites, as expected.

Did I miss a option for the haskell `curl`-call, or is it a bug? If it is a bug, is there a workaround or some `curl`-alternatives in haskell?

Greetings

Comment: You forgot to wrap call to libcurl with `withCurlDo` but anyway this code works for me (I get output then running with ghci).

Comment: @MatveyAksenov Which version of the curl haskell-package have you installed? I still get no content of 401-sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that setting the curl option `CurlFailOnError False` fixed this for me.